Register keyword: stack or heap
Some C memory management functions, such as malloc, store data into the heap instead of the (default) stack. The register keyword before a variable (e.g. register int n) specifies that n should be stored in a processor register. Does this correspond to the heap, stack, or none? In short, within the virtual memory space, where would a registered variable live?

You can only use register with automatic variables. It's stored in the same place other automatic variables are stored (typically the stack), but the keyword is a hint that it should be stored in a register rather than using memory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register

If it's a pointer variable, the location of the variable is totally independent of the data that it points to.

The CPU have a set of registers that it can access directly, without going to memory. That's the register the variable is placed in, not any RAM or other memory. With that said, the register keyword is just a hint that the compiler is allowed to completely ignore, and with it follows some limitations. Generally don't use it, the compiler will be better at deciding what should be in registers or not.

In modern optimizing compilers, the register keyword probably has very little effect. The compiler is better at deciding which variables should be kept in registers.

The only real effect is that it will prevent you from using the & operator to get the variable's address (since registers aren't necessarily  in memory and don't have addresses).

Thank you all for your answers. It should be noted: this is not a question of whether register should or not be used, nor what its effects are, but about where in memory (if in memory at all) a registered variable is located. That has been answered, so thank you.

@lafinur Define what is "memory" in your question.

It is defined. The question was specifically: does a registered var live in the heap, stack, or none? So we are talking about virtual memory, as is mentioned in the subsequent sentence.

@lafinur Compiler may use a register and not allocate dedicated address even for a regular automatic variable without register keyword, unless you refer to it's address.

@lafinur, the question supposes that "heap" and "stack" are meaningful terms.  We all do know what you mean, but these are not C-language concepts, nor is such a division an essential characteristic of computing systems on which C could be implemented.  They are not meaningful in the context of the C language specifications.

C doesn't define where exactly a register variable has to be stored. It might end up as just a register but it could also be placed on the stack.
From a C23 draft - §6.7.2 Storage-class specifiers:

A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

and:

The implementation can treat any register declaration simply as an auto declaration. However, whether or not addressable storage is used, the address of any part of an object declared with storage-class specifier register cannot be computed [...].


C also doesn't specify where any other kind of variable is stored.
